# Absolute Uncertainty in logarithm base 10

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, error-analysis

I have this question in alevels paper and, I don't understand how to find the uncertainty in the value of T ( image attached). T is time period, and is **t/10**. Check the table in image for values! If anyone can just tell me the basic formula to be used in this case to find uncertainties in values of **logT** , I will appreciate it! Thanks!

> (b) Values of $l$ and $t$ are given in Fig. 2.2.
> $$
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline l / \mathrm{cm} & t / \mathrm{s} & T / \mathrm{s} & \lg (l / \mathrm{cm}) & \lg (T / \mathrm{s}) \\
> \hline 95.0 & 19.6 \pm 0.2 & & & \\
> \hline 85.0 & 18.4 \pm 0.2 & & & \\
> \hline 75.0 & 17.4 \pm 0.2 & & & \\
> \hline 65.0 & 16.2 \pm 0.2 & & & \\
> \hline 55.0 & 14.8 \pm 0.2 & & & \\
> \hline 45.0 & 13.4 \pm 0.2 & & & \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
> Calculate and record values of $T / \mathrm{s}, \lg (l / \mathrm{cm})$ and $\lg (T / \mathrm{s})$ in Fig. 2.2. Include the absolute uncertainties in $\lg (T / \mathrm{s})$.